# iPhone Application Orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I forced the view in my iPhone application to always be in "landscape view." What this apparently does, though, is when iPhone is positioned vertically, the view, in landscape, is positioned vertically, as well, and half of it is missing off-screen. How would I make it so that the full landscape view is always visible (If the iPhone is held horizontally, the full landscape view is visible, and if the iPhone is held vertically, the full view is also visible, only rotated on its side)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

steps to launch app in landscape mode:

Technical Note TN2244
Launching your Application in Landscape
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2244/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a series of layered views?  In the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation()` method of the base view controller, add:

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
```

It would not hurt to add that to all view controllers if the app is all landscape all the time.

Comment: This worked. However, when the application starts up with the device in Portrait orientation, the problem is still there (Until I flip the device, of course). How do I make sure things are how I want them from the start?

Comment: I am not at my Mac right now to check, but I believe you can set the initial orientation via a property in the applications main plist.

Answer (score 0):

Try do with this in the viewController

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
  {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
  }
```